# Embedded array push not working in mongoose - push not defined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-schema

Hie,

I have a schema of this format.

```
var parentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    parent_id : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    country_id : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    child: [childSchema]
});

var childSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    child_name: String,
    standard_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    child_id : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    total_gold: { type: Number},
    total_diamonds:{ type: Number },
    total_hearts: { type: Number},
    subjects: [subjectSchema]
});

var subjectSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    subject_name :String,
    grade_name : String,
    games: [gameSchema]
});

var gameSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    id:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    game_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    gold: { type: Number },
    diamonds: { type: Number },
    hearts: { type: Number },
    plays: { type: Number },
    best_score: { type: Number },
    is_locked: String
});
```

Iam trying to insert data into the models this way.

```
var parent = new Parent();
parent.username = req.body.username;
parent.password = req.body.password;

var games = new Games({gold:0,diamonds:0,hearts:0,plays:0,best_score:0,is_locked:false});


var subjects = new Subjects({subject_name:req.body.subjectname,grade_name:req.body.gradename});

var child = new Child({child_name:req.body.childname,total_gold:0,total_diamonds:0,total_hearts:0});
```

After the data is inserted into models iam adding the models to parent document this way.

```
subjects.games.push(games);
child.subjects.push(subjects);
parent.child.push(child);
parent.save(function (err, parent) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
});
```

When i using the above code iam getting error saying push is undefined for subjects.

Error stack is as follows:

```
 subjects.games.push(games);
                           ^
 TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined
at Promise.module.exports.saltAndHash (d:\BWApis\BWApiProject\app\server\router.js:926:32)
at Promise.onResolve (d:\BWApis\BWApiProject\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:177:8)
at Promise.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Promise.emit (d:\BWApis\BWApiProject\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:84:38)
at Promise.fulfill (d:\BWApis\BWApiProject\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:97:20)
at Object.cb (d:\BWApis\BWApiProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1145:30)
at Object.exports.tick (d:\BWApis\BWApiProject\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mquery\lib\utils.js:137:16)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:330:15)
```

Comment: check child vs children problem

Comment: My bad.I pasted wrong stack.Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing wrong here.

```
subjects.games.push(games);
child.subjects.push(subjects);
parent.child.push(child);
parent.save(function (err, parent) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
});
```

**Try this - though it will work According to your ques, But this is also a wrong method**

```
games.save(function(er, newGame) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    subjects.games.push(newGame);
    subject.save(function(err, newSubject) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        child.subjects.push(newSubject);
        child.save(function(err, newChild) {
            if (err)
                throw err;
            parent.child.push(newChild);
            parent.save(function (err, parent) {
                if (err)
                    throw err;
            });
        })        
    })
})
```

**Your Schema Structure is wrong**

**You should go with this Schema Structure**

```
var parentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    parent_id : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    country_id : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    child: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Child'}] //Note: Child is model name not any name or Schema Name
});

var childSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    child_name: String,
    standard_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    child_id : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    total_gold: { type: Number},
    total_diamonds:{ type: Number },
    total_hearts: { type: Number},
    subjects: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Subjects'}]
});

var subjectSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    subject_name :String,
    grade_name : String,
    games: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Games'}]
});

var gameSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    id:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    game_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    gold: { type: Number },
    diamonds: { type: Number },
    hearts: { type: Number },
    plays: { type: Number },
    best_score: { type: Number },
    is_locked: String
});



games.save(function(er, newGame) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    subjects.games.push(newGame._id);
    subject.save(function(err, newSubject) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        child.subjects.push(newSubject._id);
        child.save(function(err, newChild) {
            if (err)
                throw err;
            parent.child.push(newChild._id);
            parent.save(function (err, parent) {
                if (err)
                    throw err;
            });
        })        
    })
})
```